# How to run non-Caffe model in Caffe

Tags: caffe, inference

I want to run inference using some ConvNet on Caffe. The only issue is I already have the weights and bias in raw format and I don't want to re-train it on Caffe.

Now Caffe requires two input file:

- .prototxt (for Network info)
- .caffemodel (for weights and bias)

Here .prototxt file can be generated easily, but is it possible to generate .caffemodel using raw weights and bias?

Answer (score 1):

The process of manually manipulating a Caffe model is called [Net Surgery](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/net_surgery.ipynb).

Specifically, `net.params()` allows you to access the net's parameters directly.